# masking after redrection using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mask

I have read many examples that use the .htaccess file method to mask a url. None of them works for me. It might be something simple that I am missing. Please bare with me.

Here is what i want to do:

I have a subdomain under a dns name, lets say it is `mysub.domain` . I have an `index.html` file there that redirects lets say to `mycomplex.dns.site`. The redirection is done successfully via

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://mycomplex.dns.site:8081" /> in my index.html
```

When the page is loaded in Firefox, the url on the address bar, says `http://mycomplex.dns.site:8081`.

I don't want this I would like to show `mysub.domain`, so I created a .htaccess file in the /var/www/html target directory that says:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/mycomplex.dns.site:8081$" "http://mysub.domain/intex.html" [R]
```

And this doesn't work! I keep getting the url as `mycomplex.dns.site:8081`

I have tried to redirect with a .htaccess redirection in  `mysub.domain` which works but the target `mycomplex.dns.site` url description remains.

The subdomain is in a provider where I have no apache2 control.
The host computer with the complex name is in a raspberry with apache2. There I can control things and apache2. I have tried many variations but it doesn't work. Should it be something is Apache2 config files?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. You can't hide a port via .htaccess file.

Comment: What if we won't hide the port number? Can we make it work like `mysub.domain:8081`

Comment: @Gerald Schneider
 The subdomain is in a provider where I have no apache2 control. The host computer with the complex name is in a raspberry with apache2.