# masking URL after redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2, mask

I re-post my question in the event that I will be more clear as to what I would like to do.
I have a subdomain under a dns name, lets say it is `mysub.domain` . This subdomain is in a remote provider where I have no apache2 control.  The file system available has an index.html file that can redirect to a web page (just one html page), lets say to `mycomplex.dns.site:8081`.
This latter site resides in an rpi that I have full control ie Apache2/php/etc.
The redirection is done successfully via
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://mycomplex.dns.site:8081" />` in my index.html.

To summarize, I write  `mysub.domain` in the URL command line and after the redirection I see `http://mycomplex.dns.site:8081` in the url line.
That is not what I want. I would like to keep showing `mysub.domain`.
How do I do this? I googled and found this solution involving .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/mycomplex.dns.site:8081$" "http://mysub.domain/intex.html" [R]
```

This doesn't work , I keep getting the url as `mycomplex.dns.site:8081`.
Is it some misspelling in the .htaccess file or I am missing the point of masking? I suppose that this .htaccess is in the target directory `/var/www/html/`
Should I add the server name `mysub.domain` in apache2 virtual config file, but again I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: Please don't just repost your question when it get's closed. You can edit your question to improve it and it can be reopened. As you [were already told](https://serverfault.com/questions/1099097/masking-after-redrection-using-htaccess), what you want is not possible using rewrites, you need to configure Apache as a reverse proxy to do that.

Comment: And since you already disclosed that the target is a raspberry pi at your home, your question is off topic for this site anyway. This site is for business environments.

Comment: Don't run your http server on port 8081, and configure DNS the way you want it.

Comment: Rewrite will only change the file path part of the URL, not the host/port information.